# Durandal & require.js causing issues with paths for 3rd party scripts when bundling

Tags: requirejs, durandal

It's not specific to a script - I've had the same problem with two different web editors now (TinyMCE and now CKEditor).

In my bundleconfig.cs I have:

```
.Include("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")
```

Which is located in /Scripts/ckeditor and it works fine in visual studio on my development machine.

As soon as I publish the site to a local dev server, I immediately get errors when it tries to load associated resources to that file:

```
GET http://example.com/config.js?t=H0CG 404 (Not Found)
GET http://example.com/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=H0CG 
GET http://example.com/lang/en.js?t=H0CG
```

As you can see, it's trying to load the scripts from the wrong location - it should be looking for `http://example.com/Scripts/ckeditor/config.js` etc.

How do I tell Durandal/require.js to retain the "Scripts/ckeditor" part in there when loading those files?

The script is needed on a few different pages, so I'm loading it in the bundle. I could, instead, load it via require.js at the top of each page where it's needed. Is that the better solution rather than having it loaded at the site load?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by editing my main.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'ckeditor-jquery': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'ckeditor-core']
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'bootstrap': '../Scripts/bootstrap',
        'ckeditor-core': '../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor',
        'ckeditor-jquery':'../Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery'

    }
});
```

Then in the viewmodel that needs it I have:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'ckeditor-jquery'], function (app, dc, ckjq) {
    var vm = function () {
    etc...
```

I removed any reference to ckeditor from the bundleconfig.cs file. This way it only loads the scripts when it needs them.